# how to use only Javascript to add new Bootstrap switch dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

how to use only Javascript to add new Bootstrap switch dynamically

like this:

```
<div class="toggle btn btn-primary" data-toggle="toggle" role="button" style="width: 61.0781px; height: 38px;">
 <input type="checkbox" checked="" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="primary">
 <div class="toggle-group">
  <label class="btn btn-primary toggle-on">
   On
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-light toggle-off">
   Off
  </label>
  <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-light">
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

from this site [text](https://gitbrent.github.io/bootstrap4-toggle/)

---

button can be added like this

```
<script>
        function addButton() {
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            element.type = "button";
            element.value = "View Info";
            element.name = "getInfo";
            element.className = "btn btn-info btn-lg";
        }
</script>
```

```js
function addButton() {
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = "button";
  element.value = "View Info";
  element.name = "getInfo";
  element.className = "btn btn-info btn-lg";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>

<div class="toggle btn btn-primary" data-toggle="toggle" role="button" style="width: 61.0781px; height: 38px;">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="primary">
  <div class="toggle-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary toggle-on">
   On
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-light toggle-off">
   Off
  </label>
    <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-light">
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a question here? Not sure what is being asked.

Comment: I have a clean html document. I can use javascript. I can add a simple button, but I can't add a toggle like the example above

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a parent element in your HTML under which you'd add this newly created switch.

Say you have a `div#switch-host` in your HTML.

```
<div id="switch-host"></div>
```

Then you'd implement a JS function which will add your switch to this div as

```
function addSwitch(hostEl) {
  const host = document.getElementById(hostEl);

  const inputEl = document.createElement("input");
  inputEl.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  inputEl.setAttribute("checked", false);
  inputEl.dataset.toggle = "toggle";

  host.appendChild(inputEl);
}
```

And then call this function as

```
addSwitch("switch-host");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after.  I used some template because I don't like all that in code.  I then modified the values with jQuery since this is a jQuery plugin.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

```js
/* not used
function addButton() {
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = "button";
  element.value = "View Info";
  element.name = "getInfo";
  element.className = "btn btn-info btn-lg";
}
*/
function clickHandler(event) {
  console.log('clicked toggle');
}

function addSwitchButton() {
  const container = document.getElementById("switchcontainer");
  const template = document.getElementById("myswitch");
  const clone = template.content
    .firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
  clone.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
  $(clone).find('.toggle-on').text('View Info');
  $(clone).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('name', 'getInfo');

  $(clone).bootstrapToggle();
  container.appendChild(clone);
}
const addme = document.querySelector(".add-switch");
addme.addEventListener("click", addSwitchButton);
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#switchcontainer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20em;
  height: 10em;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: solid #00FF00;
}

.toggle.btn.btn-primary {
  width: 9em;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="add-switch">Add Switch</button>
<div id="switchcontainer"></div>

<template id="myswitch">
<div class="toggle btn btn-primary"  role="button">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="primary">
  <div class="toggle-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary toggle-on">On</label>
    <label class="btn btn-light toggle-off">Off</label>
    <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-light"></span>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```